# Using df1 as a lookup table for df2, df2 has more unique values than df1 in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, lookup

I have a df with US citizens state and I would like to use that as a lookup for world citizens

df1=

```
[Sam, New York;
Nick, California;
Sarah, Texas]
```

df2 =

```
[Sam;
Phillip;
Will;
Sam]
```

I would like to either df2.replace() with the states or create df3 where my output is:

```
[New York;
NaN;
NaN;
New York]
```

I have tried mapping with set_index and dict(zip()) but have had no luck so far.

Thank you.

Comment: That is not a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

How about this method:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Sam','New York'],['Nick','California'],['Sarah','Texas']],\
    columns = ['name','state'])
display(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Sam','Phillip','Will','Sam'],\
    columns = ['name'])
display(df2)

df2.merge(right=df1,left_on='name',right_on='name',how='left')
```

resulting in

```
name    state
0   Sam New York
1   Nick    California
2   Sarah   Texas

name
0   Sam
1   Phillip
2   Will
3   Sam

name    state
0   Sam New York
1   Phillip NaN
2   Will    NaN
3   Sam New York
```

you can then filter for just the state column in the merged dataframe